# debian: Can't login connect to MySQL server

Tags: debian

When I am trying to connect to MySQL server on my debian server, it gives an error belwo.

```
    mysql -u root -p
    Enter password:
    ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

When I type:

```
ls -l /var/run/ | grep mysqld
drwxr-xr-x 2 mysql       root        4096 2012-04-08 16:07 mysqld
```

Any ideas to fix this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try connecting to the TCP port of the server instead of the UNIX socket. Try supplying -h localhost.